# How can I get Cart Details Options in Paypal Sync?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm calling this API: https://api.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2019-10-01T00:00:00-0700&end_date=2019-10-30T23:59:59-0700&fields=all, and it is returning all transactions but I want to retrieve cart details options although in the fields I have set it to all.

I have read https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/sync/#list-transactions.

What I want is the following (but via API):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, using PayPal APIs for reporting is a bad idea, for various reasons -- including slowness. But even if they were good for this use case, I know of no way to get the shopping cart data you mention in a list via an API. The only possible solution might be to first get the list without shopping cart data and then query each transaction individually (one API cal per transaction) to get its shopping cart details, but this is incredibly inefficient.

So basically, you should:

1. Record and save all shopping cart details at transaction time, in your own database, using IPN/webhooks as a listener if necessary
2. Manually use the activity download of your screenshot to download a CSV, if it's ever necessary to backfill information from the past.
3. Not use reporting APIs.